# How to measure Data downloading and uploading speed in android?

Tags: android

I'm making an android app in which I have to measure data downloading and uploading speed and whether it is connected to wifi or with any other mode ("EDGE","HSPA","LTE" etc). Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class to do that.

If you want to split into GSM/HSPA/LTE etc. I would use a [network change listener](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) and use [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkType%28%29) to get the current mobile network type.

The TrafficStats class is easy to use, just measure it periodical and you can get a speed out of it. More info on how to implement a network change listener: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html#detect-changes